# Angular App as client app for an Org of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am new to Hyperledger. I am using Hyperledger Fabric and defined my network, installed and instantiated the chaincode over peers.

Could someone share their thoughts on:

What should be the **steps to create client app** for each organization in the network? What is the **required configurations at client side?** Is **there a sample example** available?

**Note:** *I can't use composer.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hyperledger Fabric SDKs create your client app, SDKs are available in various programming languages. [you can find supported languages here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/fabric-sdks.html), you can create your APIs using these SDKs as per your requirement and call it from your Angular App, To get started with you can refer into sample apps provided by the Hyperledger fabric [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I already know about the sdk. But, I am confused about the required configuration of the network which is needed to connect with the network. All the available samples takes about creating and managing the network from the sdk which I dont need as I already have a network. All I need is a config to connect with the channel and execute chaincode.

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting example available under [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript-low-level) GitHub repository opn how to interact with already-created network (w/o manually creating channels, peers etc.). The idea behind this `fabcar` is stored in `query` and `invoke` methods that interact with the ledger using chaincode.

You could e.g. develop an *express.js* application to create a REST API to interact with the network using the NodeJS SDK for Hyperledger. I've tried that approach and it works just fine - with my network being started using different scripts (modified `byfn.sh`), the client application is only responsible for querying/recording data to the ledger, w/o any explicit actions taken to network itself. All you have to do is to create and enroll `admin` and `user` accounts to be able to call chaincode and you are all set.